# App Engine go context.Context has no namespace

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

After obtain a context from `ctx, ctxErr := appengine.Namespace(ctx, "MyContext")` I would expect `ctx` namespace to be populated with `MyContext`

**Code**

```
import (
...
"golang.org/x/net/context"
"google.golang.org/appengine"
)


ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
ctx, ctxErr := appengine.Namespace(ctx, "MyContext")
if ctxErr != nil {
  log.Errorf(ctx, "Failed to obtain custom namespace context, error:%s", ctxErr.Error())
  //use default if all else fails
  ctx = appengine.NewContext(r)
}
```

However this is not the case, thus causing all namespace aware API to use default namespace.

Dump of ctx produces the following (see yellow bordered output)

[image]

**Example App**

Populate `projectID := ""` with your project id, ensure you have performed authentication on your development environment and run `go run /example/app/main.go`

[Example App](https://play.golang.org/p/tYEDG16MBl)

Comment: Are you sure the call to `Namespace` isn't returning an error? Your code sample shows you assigning `ctx` but there is no mentioning of where you are assigning the error return value. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/reference#Namespace

Comment: To answer your question, yes no errors are produced when setting up namespace. However after I inspected the code used to set/manage namespace, I noticed that internal namespace function `internal.NamespacedContext(c, namespace)` uses `netcontext.WithValue(ctx, &namespaceKey, ns)` and upon dumping ctx I can see value **MyContext**. It's just not being set on namespace property, which am assume is used by internal logic in namespace aware API or maybe libs are not updated to use `namespaceKey` to obtain namespace from context.

Comment: Rather than inspecting the internals of `ctx`, have you tried using it and confirming that it isn't working? Is there actually a problem here?

Comment: @DrewMacInnis there is an issue, using the ctx with datastore api [Go_Using_namespaces_with_the_Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/multitenancy/multitenancy#Go_Using_namespaces_with_the_Datastore) which has been documented to support multi tenancy using namespace, still stores data under default namespace. Therefore it doesn't work, reason I started inspecting the internals and started this thread. Have you successfully used namespace to implement multi tenancy feature?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand your problem, this last comment better explains what you are trying to do and what isn't working. To answer your question, no I haven't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing of google api go libs, was causing the problem.

[**Long Answer**](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/issues/460)

**Short Answer**

Google Cloud API libs come in two different flavors, issues was caused by mixing of lib features from libs below.

[google-cloud-go](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go) *Recommanded*

[google-api-go-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client)